# PySpark add a column to a DataFrame from a list of strings

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm looking for a way to add a new column in a Spark DataFrames from a list of strings, in just one simple line.

Given :

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([((u'2016-10-19', u'2016-293'), 40020), 
                      ((u'2016-10-19', u'2016-293'), 143938), 
                      ((u'2016-10-19', u'2016-293'), 135891225.0)
                     ])
```

This is my code to structure my rdd and get a Dataframe :

```
def structurate_CohortPeriod_metrics_by_OrderPeriod(line):

    ((OrderDate, OrderPeriod), metrics) = line
    metrics = str(metrics)

    return OrderDate, OrderPeriod, metrics


(rdd
 .map(structurate_CohortPeriod_metrics_by_OrderPeriod)
 .toDF(['OrderDate', 'OrderPeriod', 'MetricValue'])
 .show())
```

Result :

```
+----------+-----------+-----------+
| OrderDate|OrderPeriod|MetricValue|
+----------+-----------+-----------+
|2016-10-19|   2016-293|      40020|
|2016-10-19|   2016-293|     143938|
|2016-10-19|   2016-293|135891225.0|
+----------+-----------+-----------+
```

I want to add a new column to precise the metric's name. This is what I've done :

```
def structurate_CohortPeriod_metrics_by_OrderPeriod(line):

    (((OrderDate, OrderPeriod), metrics), index) = line
    metrics = str(metrics)

    return OrderDate, OrderPeriod, metrics, index

df1 = (rdd
 .zipWithIndex()
 .map(structurate_CohortPeriod_metrics_by_OrderPeriod)
 .toDF(['OrderDate', 'OrderPeriod', 'MetricValue', 'index']))
```

Then

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType

df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize([('0', 'UsersNb'), 
                                                 ('1', 'VideosNb'), 
                                                 ('2', 'VideosDuration')]), 
                                 StructType([StructField('index', StringType()), 
                                             StructField('MetricName', StringType())]))

df2.show()

+-----+--------------+
|index|    MetricName|
+-----+--------------+
|    0|       UsersNb|
|    1|      VideosNb|
|    2|VideosDuration|
+-----+--------------+
```

And finally :

```
(df1
 .join(df2, df1.index == df2.index)
 .drop(df2.index)
 .select('index', 'OrderDate', 'OrderPeriod', 'MetricName', 'MetricValue')
 .show())

+-----+----------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
|index| OrderDate|OrderPeriod|    MetricName|MetricValue|
+-----+----------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
|    0|2016-10-19|   2016-293|      VideosNb|     143938|
|    1|2016-10-19|   2016-293|       UsersNb|      40020|
|    2|2016-10-19|   2016-293|VideosDuration|135891225.0|
+-----+----------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
```

This is my expected output, but this method takes considerably longer. I want to do this in just one or two lines.. Something like for exemple the lit method :

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

df1.withColumn('MetricName', lit('my_string'))
```

But I need of course to put 3 different strings : 'VideosNb', 'UsersNb' and 'VideosDuration'.

Ideas ? Thank you very much !

Comment: Am I misunderstanding or are you relying on the zipWithIndex to know which metric corresponds to what? This is a bit hazardous. How many metrics do you have? I have this feeling that you either don't have the need for a RDD or DataFrame, or you can't rely on zipWithIndex to assign the right metric name to a line.

Comment: @Wilmerton : I used zipWithIndex() just in order to make possible to join the df1 with df2.. In other words, it's just to make possible to do this : **.join(df2, df1.index == df2.index)** I know that this is not the best way to get the objectif.. Thx !

Comment: I get that. Enabling the join and making a meaningful join are different things. I'm asking about the meaning of the join, knowing that the index that you get with `zipWithIndex` might not correspond to the `MetricValue` you want it to correspond.

Comment: Absolutely ! This is why I'm looking for a best way to do that ! It's just about those 3 metrics, no more :)

Comment: you mean your DataFrame will never contain more than three elements? If so, don't use an DataFrame but a more handy collection for your purpose. Here you need an ordered collection and RDD just aren't. So even if it works, this is not correct to use an RDD as an ordered collection. You are actually not *joining*, you are zipping collections ordered in the same way.